# Yarn run build SyntaxError

Tags: npm, electron, yarnpkg, electron-builder

runing Electron Build result in a SyntaxError: Unexpected token function

```
$ build
...\node_modules\read-config-file\out\main.js:72
async function readConfig(configFile) {
      ^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

Found a fix 
This issue is realated to 
https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/2986

Looks like the issue is not present in version or electron builder before 20.8.1

Comment: You should change tag yarnpkg(an open-source JavaScript package manager) , not yarn  (Yet Another Resource Negotiator).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using node version 7.x or lower, update your node installation.

Async is not supported until node version 8.